# Python-Hotshot error trying to profile a simple program

Tags: python, profiler, profiling

I was trying to learn how to profile a simple python program using hotshot, but am facing a weird error,

```
import sys
import hotshot
def main(argv):
  for i in range(1,1000):
    print i

if __name__ == "__main__":
  prof = hotshot.Profile("hotshot_edi_stats")
  b,c = prof.runcall(main(sys.argv))
  prof.close()
```

and the output,

```
.
.

995
996
997
998
999
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 9, in <module>
    b, c = prof.runcall(main(sys.argv))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/hotshot/__init__.py", line 76, in runcall
    return self._prof.runcall(func, args, kw)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Would anyone know why this happens? It looks to me like a problem with the hotshot profiler itself. Alternatively, do people have suggestions on other methods to profile python programs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And I think I've figured out something I missed for over 2 hours..

Turns out, runcall() should be called as,

```
runcall(main, self.argv)
```

and this makes things work!

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you have a way to randomly pause or interrupt the program and see the call stack, [this method always works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Comment: Nice! I like the bayesian debug theory :)